# Does some of theses messages show a faulty hardware component?

Tags: linux, debian

My computer isn't healthy. I migrated it from `Windows 7` to `Debian 9`. It improved, but still freezes many times at start especially on GNOME login screen : the mouse even didn't move, nor I can type any key. But not each time I boot it...

My computer was repaired today : a graphic card exchanged for a new one. But the issue is still here. I fear my motherboard is the cause... or something else ?

Here are the error messages I can read when I do a `sudo dmesg` command.
Does some of thoose show a specific problem you already know about ?

```
...
[    2.892722] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.905287] usb 6-1.8: firmware: failed to load ath3k-1.fw (-2)
[    2.905341] usb 6-1.8: Direct firmware load for ath3k-1.fw failed with error -2
[    2.905343] Bluetooth: Firmware file "ath3k-1.fw" not found
[    2.905394] ath3k: probe of 6-1.8:1.0 failed with error -2
[    2.905410] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    2.916197] EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.921442] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.922268] MXM: GUID detected in BIOS
[    2.922411] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (136000a1)
[    2.922465] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -12
[    2.928122] EXT4-fs (sda8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.946800] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0810
...
[    2.957813] EDAC sbridge: Seeking for: PCI ID 8086:3cf5
[    2.957819] EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
[    2.957868] EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
[    2.957915] EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
[    2.980851] usb 3-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.981265] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

What can I do to investigate other potential causes of troubles ?

I also attempted a `sudo journalctl -r -p err` and had this results :

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-05-17 17:15:29 CEST, end at Fri 2019-05-17 23:14:14 CEST. --
mai 17 20:28:07 bouleau pulseaudio[1057]: [alsa-sink-ALC898 Analog] alsa-sink.c: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
mai 17 20:28:07 bouleau pulseaudio[1057]: [alsa-sink-ALC898 Analog] alsa-sink.c: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_hda_intel'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers.
mai 17 20:28:07 bouleau pulseaudio[1057]: [alsa-sink-ALC898 Analog] alsa-sink.c: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write.
mai 17 17:57:40 bouleau /hpfax[2173]: [2173]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
mai 17 17:20:59 bouleau sudo[1903]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [marc]
mai 17 17:20:59 bouleau sudo[1903]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
mai 17 17:15:30 bouleau gnome-session-binary[619]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau avahi-daemon[551]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (136000a1)
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: Bluetooth: Firmware file "ath3k-1.fw" not found
mai 17 17:15:29 bouleau kernel: usb 6-1.8: firmware: failed to load ath3k-1.fw (-2)
```

I did also :

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Without any discovery or changes.

Comment: Your Debian installation is in a bad state - you might have done better to stay with Windows. Two problems I can see: (1) A problem with the Atheros bluetooth device having its driver missing. You might need to install it, perhaps packages firmware-linux-free,  firmware-atheros and firmware-realtek. (2) The ECC problem might require enabling ECC in your BIOS.

Comment: For future reference: I had the exact same problem today with an old machine I tried to revive from Windows 7 to Debian due to the rather light system specs, but when I switched to Ubuntu, I had none of these issues.. I think the driver support in the newer kernels and/or Ubuntu is just that much better these days..

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason for the missing reaction on keyboard/mouse in the errors.

This one

```
[    2.905287] usb 6-1.8: firmware: failed to load ath3k-1.fw (-2)
[    2.905341] usb 6-1.8: Direct firmware load for ath3k-1.fw failed with error -2
[    2.905343] Bluetooth: Firmware file "ath3k-1.fw" not found
```

means you are missing firmware for your USB wifi. So use `lsusb` to identify the wifi, and install the package for the necessary firmware. Debian separates the non-free firmwares from the other packages, so you may need to add the `non-free` part in `/etc/apt/`.

This here

```
[    2.957813] EDAC sbridge: Seeking for: PCI ID 8086:3cf5
[    2.957819] EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
[    2.957868] EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
[    2.957915] EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
```

says that the driver for the "EDAC (Error Detection And Correction) reporting" hardware doesn't work.

This one

```
[    2.922411] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (136000a1)
[    2.922465] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -12
```

says that the `nouveau` (open-source Nvidia card) kernel module couldn't recognize the chipset.

So:

1) Try to switch to a virtual console with Ctrl-Alt-F1. Can you enter your name and password? Does the mouse work?

2) Please edit your question with the output of `lspci -nn` to let us identify your graphics card.

3) The most common reasons for random freezes are (a) bad RAM (b) too high temperature. Depending on how many RAM sticks you have, try taking out each in turn and see if the problem goes away. See if you can correlate the freeze to temperature (if it doesn't freeze when you haven't used it, but freezes on second/third boot, you know the reason). Make sure all fans are working, etc.

4) In general, debugging problems works by making the system simpler until the error goes away, so you can locate the part where the problem is. So try to boot without an X server (this will need some reading if you are new to Linux) etc.